# Encode and Decode content-type 'application/soap+msbin1' for use with HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse in C#.NET

Tags: .net, wcf, c#-4.0, soap, wcf-binding

I have searched high and low looking for a simple class or set of functions to encode and decode the content type 'application/soap+msbin1'

My end goal is to be able to use HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse to interact with a webserver running a silverlight application.

Any samples or examples of either of the two items above are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was able to view the data with fiddler2

http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/version.asp

using the fiddler extension

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/wcfbinaryinspector

and encode/decode the data with

https://github.com/GDSSecurity/WCF-Binary-SOAP-Plug-In/blob/master/burp_wcf_plugin/src/NBFS.cs

Comment: For anyone else looking for this Fiddler extension, it can be found here: https://github.com/waf/WCF-Binary-Message-Inspector -- the one in this answer is 404.